# Copying CopyOnWriteArrayList to classic ArrayList, how?

Tags: java, arraylist, copyonwritearraylist

Already tried normal assignment and:

```
Collections.copy(lostPackets, historyList);
```

which throws:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
```

Is there any way to copy COWArrayList to a normal ArrayList?

Comment: is important as a developer to know how to use the documentation of any API that you intent to use, in this case, java has oficial documentation for class details, also known as javadocs, googling you are able to find [ArrayList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lostPackets.addAll(historyList);`

Note if you only want to keep the most recent records from the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` first clear the `ArrayList` using `clear()` method and then use `addAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

List arrayList = Arrays.asList(cowArrayList.toArray());

Comment: That doesn't create a java.util.ArrayList

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. Asks for 'cast' to 'List', after doing that, marks that this is impossible.  
lostPackets.addAll(historyList) worked